# How to format custom date,day in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, momentjs

I need to have this exact order using Moment.js- "Fri, Jun 26 at 13:00"
Can anyone help?

Comment: You've shown the target format.
What is the source of the date?

Comment: Have you gone through the documentation? [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/3082296)

Answer (score 0):

Try `ddd, MMM DD [at] HH:mm`

```js
console.log(moment().format('ddd, MMM DD [at] HH:mm'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment.min.js" integrity="sha256-ZsWP0vT+akWmvEMkNYgZrPHKU9Ke8nYBPC3dqONp1mY=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```